# Zend Framework 2, Doctrine2 ORM - Multiple entity relation

Tags: php, orm, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I'm using the most recent versions of ZF2 and doctrine2 orm in a project.

What I want to achieve, is a generic class "Comment" that has a relation to another entity. This entity could be from various classes "Post", "Image" aso., depending on what the comment should be related to.

The idea was to have one table for all comments and a column that defines the type of related entity, just like using the discriminator mapping.

Problem with the discriminator is that I have to create different classes  using extends, for every use case. This does not seem efficient as I will have to create quite a lot of subclasses to reflect all relations needed.

I would like to use just the base class of Comment and have one or two column(s) defining the relation like "Post:25" (target class and id in one column) or "Post" | "25" (target class an id in separate columns).

Is this possible in doctrine or is there a besser way of dealing with this?

Comment: What you will need to do is to have Post,Image etc extend a MappedSuperClass.  You can then relate a comment to the super class.  SQL itself will not support having one column in your comments table be joined to multiple tables.

Comment: I read about the MappedSuperClass in the docs, but I guess I don't understand the concept. I guess the SuperClass should be an abstract as I don't need a concret of it. But I can't relate an entity realtion to an abstract. Do you have any working example if it in mind?

Comment: I should have said to use Class Table Inheritance: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I took a good look at the Doctrine reference regarding the MappedSuperClass. Unfortunately this whole solution does not 100% fit my need. I ended up implementing a custom solution using my own discriminator column and reference to the foreign tables.